# Image, pre-image, and injection proof verification

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Just wanted to verify this proof was correct. Trying to make sure I have a handle on these subjects before the exam. Any style comments also more than welcome.

Statement:
Let $f : A \mapsto B$ be a function. $f$ is injective if and only if for all $X \subseteq A$, $f^{-1}(f(X)) \subseteq X$.

Proof:

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $f$ is injective. Let $X \subseteq A$, and let $x \in X$. Since $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}(f(X)) = \{x\} \in X$, so $f^{-1}(f(X)) \subseteq X$.

$\Leftarrow$ Suppose that for all $X \subseteq A$, $f^{-1}(f(X)) \subseteq X$. Let $a_1, a_2 \in A$ and $X = \{a_1\}$. Suppose $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$. If $a_1 \neq a_2$, then $f^{-1}(f(X)) = \{a_1, a_2\} \not \subseteq X$, a contradiction. Thus $a_1 = a_2$, so $f$ is injective.

Comment: Please typeset the proof onto your question. Math.SE uses [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but the syntax is nearly identical to Latex.

Comment: sorry about that. will fix

Comment: You should include the thing you are trying to prove too.

Comment: The statement to be proven says something about $W$, but your proof does not. What's the deal with that?

Comment: my bad i posted the wrong statement

Comment: edited it again now that's actually what i'm supposed to be proving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $\impliedby$ proof looks good.

For the $\implies$ proof two things. First, you wrote $f^{-1}(f(X)) = \{x\}$. I think you mean $f^{-1}(f(\{x\})) = \{x\}$. This is true by injectivity, but you need to argue it (give more details).

Second, you then conclude $f^{-1}(f(X)) \subseteq X$. How? This is true but you need more details. You could write $f^{-1}(f(X)) = f^{-1}(f(\bigcup_{x \in X} \{x\})) = \bigcup_{x \in X} f^{-1} (f(\{x\})) \subseteq X$. This would work.

Comment: how about this: $\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $f$ is injective. Let $X \subseteq A$, and let $x \in f^{-1}(f(X))$.  Since $f$ is injective, $x$ is the only value from $A$ that maps to a particular value in $B$, thus for all $\{x\} \subseteq X$, $f^-1(f(\{x\}) = x$. Taking the union of all of these subsets, we have that $f^-1(f(\{x_1 \dots x_n\}) = X \subseteq X$.

Comment: Looks good, except that write $X$ as $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ implies it's finite. That why you want to write $f^{-1}(f(X)) = f^{-1}(f(\bigcup_{x \in X} \{x\})) = \bigcup_{x \in X} f^{-1} (f(\{x\})) \subseteq X$.